# iOS: signal SIGTRAP with no breakpoints?

Tags: ios, crash, signals

I'm working on an iPad application and a recent change I made is causing the app to die with "signal SIGTRAP".  The stack trace doesn't help and I can't pinpoint what part of the code is causing this to happen (but I do know which function it starts from).

Without going into details about the application I was wondering if there are some general tips for debugging this kind of thing (SIGTRAP)?

I've managed to narrow down which function call causes this to happen.  The weird thing is that if I break and step into the function then it works fine.  But if I let it run without a breakpoint then it crashes.

The function calls a bunch of other things which also involve asynchronous network connections.  I put logs all over my code and all my logs print fine, so it seems something "under the hood" is causing this failure.  I'm also using a 3rd party framework which may be causing this issue?

Is this even a code-related issue?  I read somewhere that SIGTRAP is a debugger thing.

What causes this kind of crash and where should I be focusing my efforts to fix it?

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The three things I do when faced with a crash that doesn't give me enough information are: turn on breakpoints for Objective-C exceptions, enable zombies in the scheme I'm using to build/run with, and (if those don't tell me what I need) wrap the content of `main()` in a `@try/@catch` that prints out the exception's call stack symbols.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints