# Running iOS project with Xcode 6 enters debug mode

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm having problems running my iOS project with Xcode 6 beta. I believe it is entering a debug mode or something. I might have done something by pressing a key shortcut, because I didn't have the problem before. Previously the iOS simulator would appear with my app showing.

Whenever I run the project now [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4FXF.png) appears and the iOS simulator doesn't show up at all. I would like the run button to function as before. I have tried the Product->Clean feature, closing Xcode, recreating the project, removing the app from the iOS home screen, deleting the derived data and various features in the Debug menu.

What is happening and how can I revert the change?

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: I wasn't aware that the app crashed. I found the error in my code. Thank you.