# What's up with the weird breakpoint exception in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a path (`CGMutablePath`) to be used for a shape node in SpriteKit (`SKShapeNode`). I'm running my code and it stops and says `EXC_BREAKPOINT` as if there's a breakpoint in the compiler, when there isn't one. Below is a screenshot of what I have.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, *I have no breakpoint set in the compiler.* It just tends to *stop* at line 31. There's *nothing* in the logs that give a reason for this crash, if there were one to begin with.

I'm used to Objective-C stopping in `main.m` with `Thread 1: SIGABRT` and an `NSException` in the log, but this just makes no sense. Can someone please explain what's wrong?

**EDIT**: here are more screenshots to prove I have no breakpoints set. When I get an exception, it simply throws a breakpoint.

[image: Console log]

[image: UI]

Comment: Does `breakpoint list` (or `br l`) also say that you have no breakpoints set?

Comment: Do you have the break on all exceptions breakpoint set? This looks like an exception.

Comment: The listing of breakpoints on the left area says "No breakpoints."

Comment: @DDPWNAGE you might want to check my answer again since I edited it and provided a better code snippet :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That exception happens because `arc4random()` returns `UInt32` and you are subtracting a value of that, which possibly causes a negative value, which is not representable as an unsigned integer.

To fix this you may want to cast the expression to Int32 before subtracting:

```
var y = CGFloat(self.size.height / 3) + CGFloat((Int32)(arc4random() % 100) - 50)
```

Regarding the `x` value above - you create `CGFloat` and only subtract after that and therefore not encounter the above situation. Therefore a different fix would be the following

```
var y = CGFloat(self.size.height / 3) + CGFloat(arc4random() % 100) - 50
```

You basically have to ensure that at the point where you subtract something you have no unsigned type present.

The annoying thing about this is that the compiler does not warn you and the code actually works sometimes, every time when `arc4random` returns something larger than 50 and will therefore not drift into the negative values...

Incorporating the feedback and suggestion that you should not use `arc4random % something` the best solution would be to use `arc4random_uniform`.

`arc4random % something` will not yield a proper distribution of the random values, while `arc4random_uniform(something)` does - [this has already been discussed on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c).

A final note: you probably should choose 101 as upper bound instead of 100 because both `arc4random` as well as `arc4random_uniform` produce a value between 0 and (upper-1), e.g. 0 and 99. If you subtract 50 you get a value between -50 and +49. Choosing 101 will yield the desired range of -50 to +50.

```
var y = CGFloat(self.size.height / 3) + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(101)) - 50
```

Comment: Casting the `arc4random()` to an `Int32` worked for me. Still, why would it only say `EXC_BREAKPOINT?`

Comment: @DDPWNAGE no idea why it gives you such a strange error. It does not happen at compile time, it happens at runtime - no idea what the "correct" or a better error message would be.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints . `EXC_BREAKPOINT` is not caused by breakpoints. It's just a crash. Probably a raised exception.

Comment: Also: replace `arc4random() % 100` with `arc4random_uniform(100)`.

Comment: @robmayoff thanks, I included that suggestion and bumped the bound up to 101.

Comment: I never even knew about module bias and the `arc4random_uniform(upperbound)` function until just now! Statistically, it wouldn't make a **huge** difference because my upper bound is 100, but it's still great to know that. Thank you!

Comment: @DDPWNAGE It definitely makes a difference since it returns a UInt32 in the range of 0 to 4.294.967.295, modulo 100 will yield 0 to 95 a tiny bit more often than 96 to 99... not huge, but it is there ;) modulo 101 will have that point where the probabilities change after 67.

Comment: @luk2302 I thought it would just change the probability of getting 99. I'm converting to an Int32 either way.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE I think we are mixing up two different things that were wrong with the randomness: 1. modulo in general is not recommended 2. the upper bound value never gets returned - two different things, both are solved with my last code line.