# Analyse Apple crash report

Tags: ios, swift, crash

My app is rejected during the review and I received a crash report.

They say that the App will crash at startup.

I have symbolized the crash report with Xcode 7.

I can't find the error. Can anybody help me?

```
Incident Identifier: 7F51C648-88CD-4140-8AEA-08E9738BC080
CrashReporter Key:   26c02c90683f836314c526cecc4cd8fa6f92528c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [594]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DCA01744-B65D-4F46-BF63-6B55C050E90E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          any.MyApp
Version:             7 (6.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-04-16 12:43:47.47 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-04-16 12:43:45.45 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100036910
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x0000000100036910 0x100024000 + 76048
1   MyApp                           0x00000001000300a0 0x100024000 + 49312
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100030198 0x100024000 + 49560
3   UIKit                           0x0000000187778b40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
4   UIKit                           0x0000000187839118 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
5   UIKit                           0x0000000187838ff0 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
6   UIKit                           0x0000000187838238 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187837ddc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
8   UIKit                           0x0000000187837a04 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
9   UIKit                           0x000000018783796c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
10  UIKit                           0x00000001877740e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
11  QuartzCore                      0x000000018511aa28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185115634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001851154f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185114b24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018511486c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
16  QuartzCore                      0x000000018510ddd8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825ec7b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001825ea554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182514d30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
20  UIKit                           0x00000001877e7834 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
21  UIKit                           0x00000001877e1f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
22  MyApp                           0x000000010006a5ec 0x100024000 + 288236
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001820b28b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d14d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001820947d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182083648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821b5014 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001820923e8 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 244
2   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001885ad6d0 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1948
3   CoreMedia                       0x00000001849eeda0 figThreadMain + 272
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018229bb28 _pthread_body + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018229ba8c _pthread_body + 0
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001821d0b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182299020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x00000001566207f8   x3: 0x0000000156548400
    x4: 0x0000000000000007   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000830
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x00000001a08300e0  x10: 0x000001a1a083a289  x11: 0x000000150000001f
   x12: 0x0000000156508940  x13: 0x000021a1a083a289  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000073935b34
   x16: 0x0000000181cb5ef0  x17: 0x0000000181cb68dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000015654e3e0
   x20: 0xa00000000352e363  x21: 0x0000000156505ea0  x22: 0x00000001000b7e00  x23: 0x00000001000b6000
   x24: 0x0000000156548400  x25: 0x0000000100321600  x26: 0x0000000100321600  x27: 0x0000000100321600
   x28: 0xa00000000352e363  fp: 0x000000016fdd9df0   lr: 0x00000001000366ac
    sp: 0x000000016fdd9d90   pc: 0x0000000100036910 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) this is the exception you're getting. Look through this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: You need to fully symbolicate the crash report.  The first 3 lines of the stack trace are the ones that point to your app code and they aren't symbolicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are your crash:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x0000000100036910 0x100024000 + 76048
1   MyApp                           0x00000001000300a0 0x100024000 + 49312
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100030198 0x100024000 + 49560
```

The problem is that your crash log is not symbolicated.  You can re-symbolicate using the DSYM file that was created when you built the archive for submission.  If this DSYM is in your Spotlight search path, then you can re-symbolicate either in the Organizer, or the Devices window (drag the crash onto a device) or on the command line.

Command-line resymbolization is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: DSYM in my Spotlight search path was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Form Apple Documentation:

> Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]
>
> Similar to an Abnormal Exit, this exception is intended to give an
>   attached debugger the chance to interrupt the process at a specific
>   point in its execution. You can trigger this exception from your own
>   code using the __builtin_trap() function. If no debugger is attached,
>   the process is terminated and a crash report is generated.
>
> Swift code will terminate the program with this exception type if it
>   detects an unexpected condition at runtime such as:
>
> a non-optional type with a nil value a failed forced type conversion
>   Look at the Backtrace of the crashed thread to determine where the
>   unexpected condition was encountered. Additional information may have
>   also been logged to the device's console.

Sourse: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Hope this will help you.