# iOS app crashes on opening login page Swift (TestFlight Only)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, google-signin, fbsdk

My app is crashing at my login with Facebook/Google page only in TestFlight. This error doesn't appear when using the Xcode simulator. I am very baffled by this problem and don't know how to fix it.

Here is my full crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: CBEBA3B7-51CE-461F-AA78-B154009714E2
Beta Identifier:     C75146BB-6780-4080-845E-720DC1B395E0
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             App [2033]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E55D2B2-866D-43BD-9ECE-A15250AF09A1/app.app/app
Identifier:          co.app.app
Version:             1.0.6 (1.0)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-08-07 14:10:51.51 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-08-07 14:10:49.49 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.3 (13G34)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000cf698
Triggered by Thread:  0

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.232099     CFNetwork                  0x00000001832617f0 TCP Conn 0x15eadb6b0 starting SSL negotiation
0.233291     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183303e7c TCP Conn 0x15eadb6b0 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
0.234212     CFNetwork                  0x00000001833053a8 TCP Conn 0x15eadb6b0 event 1. err: 0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppName                         0x00000001000cf698 0x1000bc000 + 79512
1   AppName                         0x00000001000cde14 0x1000bc000 + 73236
2   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a3029c 0x100a08000 + 164508
3   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2ded0 0x100a08000 + 155344
4   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2dd20 0x100a08000 + 154912
5   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2d7c8 0x100a08000 + 153544
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b6f944 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132 (NSArray.m:479)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b6f7b4 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 172 (NSArray.m:496)
8   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2d584 0x100a08000 + 152964
9   FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2ca40 0x100a08000 + 150080
10  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a2ac0c 0x100a08000 + 142348
11  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a454bc 0x100a08000 + 251068
12  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a45414 0x100a08000 + 250900
13  FBSDKCoreKit                    0x0000000100a45888 0x100a08000 + 252040
14  CFNetwork                       0x00000001833f96a0 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80 (NSURLConnectionInternal.mm:124)
15  CFNetwork                       0x00000001833f9630 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 200 (NSURLConnectionInternal.mm:121)
16  CFNetwork                       0x00000001833f97a4 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56 (NSURLConnectionInternal.mm:139)
17  CFNetwork                       0x000000018325f39c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100 (URLConnectionClient.cpp:2132)
18  CFNetwork                       0x000000018335341c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 108 (URLConnectionClient.cpp:1896)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001826c947c _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:506)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001826d27b8 _dispatch_block_invoke + 540 (queue.c:2171)
21  CFNetwork                       0x000000018324bac0 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 36 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:363)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5c67c CFArrayApplyFunction + 68 (CFArray.c:707)
23  CFNetwork                       0x000000018324b9a4 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:317)
24  CFNetwork                       0x000000018324b864 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312 (CFNRunLoopMultiplexer.c:282)
25  CFNetwork                       0x000000018324b690 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68 (CFNRunLoopMultiplexer.c:47)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c3509c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1761)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c34b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c32830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724 (CFRunLoop.c:2536)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
30  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184444088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
31  UIKit                           0x0000000187e46088 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
32  AppName                         0x00000001000d5244 0x1000bc000 + 102980
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001826fa8b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001828194d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001826dc7d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232 (source.c:2542)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001826cb648 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52 (source.c:2573)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001827fcfd8 mach_msg_trap + 8 (syscall_sw.h:105)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001827fce54 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c34c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c32964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032 (CFRunLoop.c:2607)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b5cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001832ddbcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412 (NSURLConnection.mm:325)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183653e4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000 (NSThread.m:1134)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e3b28 _pthread_body + 156 (pthread.c:656)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e3a8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:692)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1028 thread_start + 4 (pthread_asm.s:197)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818344 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c3b1c8 __CFSocketManager + 648 (CFSocket.c:2128)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e3b28 _pthread_body + 156 (pthread.c:656)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e3a8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:692)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1028 thread_start + 4 (pthread_asm.s:197)

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182818b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1999)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001828e1020 start_wqthread + 4 (pthread_asm.s:190)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00000001828da8f4   x2: 0x000000015d7e38d0   x3: 0x0000000000000006
    x4: 0x000000015e925ec0   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000064   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x00000001a167e0e0  x10: 0x000000015d7e4000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x000000015d7e0000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x00000001822fdef0  x17: 0x00000001822fea74  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000015e859770
   x20: 0x0000000100f03a66  x21: 0x000000015d792070  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0xc000000000000004
   x24: 0x000000015d7f94e0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000015e9b5cf0  x27: 0x800000000000000a
   x28: 0x000000015ea565a0  fp: 0x000000016fd42040   lr: 0x00000001000cf264
    sp: 0x000000016fd41e50   pc: 0x00000001000cf698 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Hope you all can help! Thanks!

Comment: The code and crash line of the crashing place is more informative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: Where can I find the line that causes the crash?