# Swift App crash on device work fine on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, crash-reports

I have an app that works fine on simulator but when I run it on Ipad it crashes randomly. I am really in big trouble I have to submit the app tomorrow.

I cant understand the crash report, and the app is big I have 40 files, and many segues and http requests. its impossible tocheck on each file!
where to look?

does this hint on anything:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010014c164
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Please guys any help will be great, am in big trouble!

Update:

the application has many api calls, after doing like 4 - 5 calls the app exit and stay in the background.

I can't know if its the actual issue, but I am guessing here because staying on the same page, the app won't crash.

what should I do guys?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to give you concrete help with this information.

I would suggest you add a crash report tool to your app (like [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)).
That way you will get a readable report when an actual device crash and a will be more reasonable to fix.

*It is a good practice to have a crash report tool in any production app.*

Comment: Hi bro, I now notice it always crash on the page that perform the calling to api, if the api is on http not https, does that have an effect on the app? this is an ad hoc build for testing

Comment: what info can I provide to help narrow down the issue?

Comment: Well, Since iOS9 Apple ATS requires https connection only, you cannot call non-https API from your app (there are hacks to allow it but apple will reject your app if you do so). You will have to make your server over https.