# need help to find crash point, crash log from apple team

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, crash-reports

My app get reject from app store because of "Your app crashed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.2 connected to an IPv6 network" Specifically, they found that after Google login, the application crashes.

- Offline
- On Wi-Fi

but its working well in my devices. need help to find crash point:

```
{"app_name":"myapp","timestamp":"2017-01-04 11:09:06.02 -0800","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"6d0edca6-b9f2-33b5-81b8-15b6079c9aad","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.1.13.6","bundleID":"co.myapp.myappios","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)","incident_id":"9D930BF8-741C-46A5-9CCB-EBDF38A7653E","name":"myapp"}
Incident Identifier: 9D930BF8-741C-46A5-9CCB-EBDF38A7653E
CrashReporter Key:   fd80a1da09c1e30eb42b5f585c979b0fef267c8e
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             myapp [2038]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A449E6F-F413-4FDB-B2B3-2A4240699EF8/myapp.app/myapp
Identifier:          co.myapp.myappios
Version:             1.1.13.6 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           co.myapp.myappios [668]


Date/Time:           2017-01-04 11:09:05.9334 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-01-04 11:09:04.6057 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010005b620
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myapp                           0x000000010005b620 0x100020000 + 243232
1   myapp                           0x00000001001cba14 0x100020000 + 1751572
2   myapp                           0x00000001001d009c 0x100020000 + 1769628
3   myapp                           0x00000001001cc558 0x100020000 + 1754456
4   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x000000018f50928c 0x18f505000 + 17036
5   Foundation                      0x000000018fd20568 0x18fc0b000 + 1135976
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fd206cc 0x18fc0b000 + 1136332
7   myapp                           0x00000001001cac30 0x100020000 + 1748016
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1fc 0x18e089000 + 4604
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1bc 0x18e089000 + 4540
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08ed68 0x18e089000 + 23912
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ae810 0x18f0d1000 + 907280
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ac3fc 0x18f0d1000 + 898044
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f0da2b8 0x18f0d1000 + 37560
14  GraphicsServices                0x0000000190b8e198 0x190b82000 + 49560
15  UIKit                           0x000000019511a7fc 0x1950a0000 + 501756
16  UIKit                           0x0000000195115534 0x1950a0000 + 480564
17  myapp                           0x000000010024bf20 0x100020000 + 2277152
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018e0bd5b8 0x18e0b9000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293344 0x18e292000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293160 0x18e292000 + 4448
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293344 0x18e292000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1b1188 0x18e1b0000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1b0ff8 0x18e1b0000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ae5d0 0x18f0d1000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ac1ec 0x18f0d1000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f0da2b8 0x18f0d1000 + 37560
5   Foundation                      0x000000018fc1726c 0x18fc0b000 + 49772
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fc37dd0 0x18fc0b000 + 183760
7   UIKit                           0x0000000195a8ec38 0x1950a0000 + 10415160
8   Foundation                      0x000000018fd14e68 0x18fc0b000 + 1089128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295850 0x18e292000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295760 0x18e292000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d94 0x18e292000 + 3476

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.network.connections
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_network.dylib         0x000000018e242e10 0x18e21e000 + 151056
1   libsystem_network.dylib         0x000000018e242e00 0x18e21e000 + 151040
2   libsystem_network.dylib         0x000000018e24c480 0x18e21e000 + 189568
3   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba07a5c 0x19ba02000 + 23132
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba54010 0x19ba02000 + 335888
5   libsystem_coretls.dylib         0x000000018e176a08 0x18e16c000 + 43528
6   libsystem_coretls.dylib         0x000000018e17c25c 0x18e16c000 + 66140
7   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba552e4 0x19ba02000 + 340708
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1fc 0x18e089000 + 4604
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1bc 0x18e089000 + 4540
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e0983dc 0x18e089000 + 62428
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08d9a4 0x18e089000 + 18852
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09a34c 0x18e089000 + 70476
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09a0ac 0x18e089000 + 69804
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e2932a0 0x18e292000 + 4768
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d88 0x18e292000 + 3464

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFNetwork.Connection
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cf8e8 0x18e1b0000 + 129256
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018e29047c 0x18e28b000 + 21628
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018dc48cec 0x18dc30000 + 101612
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018dc43800 0x18dc30000 + 79872
4   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x000000018e0dfa38 0x18e0df000 + 2616
5   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x000000018e0dfa28 0x18e0df000 + 2600
6   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba3f5a0 0x19ba02000 + 251296
7   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x000000018e0dfa28 0x18e0df000 + 2600
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1bc 0x18e089000 + 4540
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e0983dc 0x18e089000 + 62428
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08d9a4 0x18e089000 + 18852
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09a34c 0x18e089000 + 70476
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09a0ac 0x18e089000 + 69804
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e2932a0 0x18e292000 + 4768
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFNetwork.Connection
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cf8e8 0x18e1b0000 + 129256
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09d0c4 0x18e089000 + 82116
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09d1ec 0x18e089000 + 82412
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09adb8 0x18e089000 + 73144
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba3e224 0x19ba02000 + 246308
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000019ba4b294 0x19ba02000 + 299668
6   CFNetwork                       0x000000018f9a9800 0x18f800000 + 1742848
7   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa20358 0x18f800000 + 2229080
8   CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa1ec58 0x18f800000 + 2223192
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1bc 0x18e089000 + 4540
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e0977f0 0x18e089000 + 59376
11  CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa1ebfc 0x18f800000 + 2223100
12  CFNetwork                       0x000000018f93a84c 0x18f800000 + 1288268
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a1bc 0x18e089000 + 4540
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e095ab0 0x18e089000 + 51888
15  CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa3a2a8 0x18f800000 + 2335400
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f0d9c18 0x18f0d1000 + 35864
17  CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa3a18c 0x18f800000 + 2335116
18  CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa3b4b4 0x18f800000 + 2340020
19  CFNetwork                       0x000000018fa3b220 0x18f800000 + 2339360
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1aeb5c 0x18f0d1000 + 908124
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ae4a4 0x18f0d1000 + 906404
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ac0a4 0x18f0d1000 + 897188
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f0da2b8 0x18f0d1000 + 37560
24  CFNetwork                       0x000000018f8df8f0 0x18f800000 + 915696
25  Foundation                      0x000000018fd14e68 0x18fc0b000 + 1089128
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295850 0x18e292000 + 14416
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295760 0x18e292000 + 14176
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d94 0x18e292000 + 3476

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293344 0x18e292000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 10 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 10:
0   myapp                           0x000000010038157c 0x100020000 + 3544444
1   myapp                           0x0000000100378894 0x100020000 + 3508372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295850 0x18e292000 + 14416
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295760 0x18e292000 + 14176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d94 0x18e292000 + 3476

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293160 0x18e292000 + 4448
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.nsurlsessiond
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e20331c 0x18e202000 + 4892
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e206168 0x18e202000 + 16744
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000018e2060ac 0x18e202000 + 16556
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018dc43624 0x18dc30000 + 79396
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018dc51ae4 0x18dc30000 + 137956
5   Foundation                      0x000000018fc87f98 0x18fc0b000 + 511896
6   Foundation                      0x000000018fc122e4 0x18fc0b000 + 29412
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018e2d38f4 0x18e2ce000 + 22772
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018e2d13e8 0x18e2ce000 + 13288
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08a28c 0x18e089000 + 4748
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08dd80 0x18e089000 + 19840
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e098210 0x18e089000 + 61968
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08d1e0 0x18e089000 + 16864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e098210 0x18e089000 + 61968
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e08d9a4 0x18e089000 + 18852
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09926c 0x18e089000 + 66156
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018e09faf8 0x18e089000 + 92920
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e29314c 0x18e292000 + 4428
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cf23c 0x18e1b0000 + 127548
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1b5468 0x18f0d1000 + 935016
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295850 0x18e292000 + 14416
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295760 0x18e292000 + 14176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d94 0x18e292000 + 3476

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1b1188 0x18e1b0000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1b0ff8 0x18e1b0000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ae5d0 0x18f0d1000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f1ac1ec 0x18f0d1000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f0da2b8 0x18f0d1000 + 37560
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018f127b44 0x18f0d1000 + 355140
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000195f96120 0x195f28000 + 450848
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295850 0x18e292000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e295760 0x18e292000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d94 0x18e292000 + 3476

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293160 0x18e292000 + 4448
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018e1cfa88 0x18e1b0000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e293344 0x18e292000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018e292d8c 0x18e292000 + 3468

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000017824b2e0   x1: 0x0000000000000002   x2: 0x0000000100c46fbc   x3: 0x0000000100c46bac
    x4: 0x0000000178c60e00   x5: 0x0000000000000067   x6: 0x0000000100c85608   x7: 0x000000017828a8d8
    x8: 0x000000017824b2e8   x9: 0x0000000000000008  x10: 0x0000000000000014  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x00000001780f0c60  x13: 0x0000000001153500  x14: 0x00000000011534c0  x15: 0x0000000001153401
   x16: 0x0000000100c54ca4  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000017824b2e0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x000000017824b300  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000174153cf0  x26: 0x1fff000000000000  x27: 0x000000017824b2e0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016fdde830   lr: 0x000000010005b4d8
    sp: 0x000000016fdde750   pc: 0x000000010005b620 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Please let me know if anybody has any idea.

Comment: Are you using any static IP for server requests? if so they are not IPv6 compliance, or it can be problem with your server url check the IPv6 validity for your URL [here](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php)

Comment: No, I am using domain name. its validate with IPV6. i check on website you share. @iphonic

Comment: Are you using Alamofire ?  If yes than which version.

Comment: yes i am using Alamofire 4.0.

Comment: Also try to see here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613767/2908082

Comment: I have no debugger enable in my app build.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to Symbolicate the crash report based on the crash data you have. Do you have the debug symbols enabled in your app so that you can do the symbolication successfully?