# Swift 3 (Xcode): Program stopping at nonexistent breakpoint

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I have been trying to run my app on another person's iPhone (and I have run it before on this person's phone without any issues before). However, this time when I ran the program on their phone, I was getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10004830c)

every time my program executed a certain line. It also once warned me that it *failed to send the k packet*. When I run it on *my* phone, I have no issues. I have made sure to delete all breakpoints, and I have even used lldb to make sure there are no breakpoints - and there aren't. This is what it says when I ask for a list of all breakpoints and delete all breakpoints:

> (lldb) breakpoint list
>   No breakpoints currently set.
>   (lldb) breakpoint delete
>   error: No breakpoints exist to be deleted.

I have restarted this person's phone a few times, and that didn't change anything. I have also tried commenting the line out and rewriting it underneath it but that didn't help either. I have searched for other posts with the same issue, but most are for java and other languages, and the ones for Swift don't work for me or I don't understand what they are saying. Please help me because I'm really confused. Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**  I have realised that maybe the problem has something to do with the newer 64bit devices. My phone (which my program works on, and is a 32bit) is an iPhone 5C. The other devices which my program doesn't work on are an iPad 2 and iPhone 6S (which are 64bit).

Comment: Your application is just crashing, that's what the log means. It doesn't mean a debugger breakpoing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: have you ever try to run the application without connecting his iphone to your computer? sometimes it is occur just in debug mode...

Comment: @Sulthan that is for SIGTRAP errors which is not what I am having.

Comment: @Hamidsh Yes I have tried without connecting the phone.

Comment: @J.Treutlein That doesn't matter. It's a crash.

Comment: This answer may help explain the issue, but I'm uncertain if it provides a solution to the problem. If I'm wrong, please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: you should check device log by connecting device to mac and find the exact log , is there any proxy u set for using app on friend phone ?

Comment: No I haven't set anything, and how do I find the 'exact' log

Comment: @J.Treutlein It's a crash so just debug the application. *Put a breakpoint there* and see why the app is crashing.

Comment: It doesn't show any sign of an error, all I'm doing is checking if a list of string contains a string like: if list.contains(string) {