# Strugling to release iOs App to Store with net Maui

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I have been strugling to release an iOs app that was developed using Net Maui (Dot Net 8.0) the last 3 weeks with Apple keeping on rejecting the application due to the most stupid reasons. in any case the last file that I submitted I tested on 3 different devices which I had available with me and it was rejected again saying on an iPhone 13 it crashed at startup but I cannot figure out what the cause is.

I have opend up the crash log they sent and symbolized it, but being a MS guy I do not truelly understand what the crash log mean

Here is the raw crash log apple attached
https://pastebin.com/sqyMbrb1

```
{"app_name":"SocialBean.App","timestamp":"2024-02-25 11:07:02.00 -0800","app_version":"1.0.5","slice_uuid":"baee96db-0c92-307c-ba5d-413a6d78d14b","adam_id":"6477769556","build_version":"1","platform":2,"bundleID":"za.co.socialbean","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.3.1 (21D61)","roots_installed":0,"name":"SocialBean.App","incident_id":"A262C146-C4A7-465F-9927-E62DC8915072"}
```

Here is the symbolized log apple attached
https://pastebin.com/XR9j5S3K

```
Incident Identifier: A262C146-C4A7-465F-9927-E62DC8915072
CrashReporter Key:   efecb798cd46759d0d977bedd0be676598da97a1
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,4
Process:             SocialBean.App [8823]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AA720717-9B7B-42C7-B45C-3366F970CFDF/SocialBean.App.app/SocialBean.App
Identifier:          za.co.socialbean
Version:             1.0.5 (1)
AppStoreTools:       15C5500a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           za.co.socialbean [2707]
```

Any ideas, suggestions or help would be appreciated. This is my only app of 4 I released this year that is giving me endless headaches

Comment: They state that it crashes on an iphone 13 but the hardware model states that it is an iphone 14? Also is your app called SocialBean? I just found this useful page on apples site https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/examining-the-fields-in-a-crash-report

Comment: This might also be worth looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints

Comment: `iPhone14,4` is an iPhone 13 mini. The identifiers are not the same as the model numbers. I'd run the app in the simulator for that model and OS combination.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am going to try to run it on a simulator

Comment: The crash happened on thread 6.  `abort` was called, terminating your app. The stack trace looks odd because on thread 6 I can see UICollectionView layout calculations. All UI tasks must run on the main thread. I don't know about Maui development but in native iOS development you need to ensure that if you fetch data from the network that you explicitly return to the main thread when updating the UI with that data, so maybe look at that

Comment: @Paulw11 I have made a few changes in that, hopefully it works. if so I will let you know

Comment: @Paulw11 I suspect you might have been correct, in Maui in debug it doesn't seem to throw an exception and works if a background thread updates the UI, after making a few tweaks to use a dispatcher and I submitted again the app was approved